# Could a Hilbert Space be defined as a Tensor with infinite dimension and infinite magnitude?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

If a Hilbert space is a vector space that is not limited by finite dimension, can it be described as a Tensor with infinite dimension and magnitude since both contain an inner product?

Comment: What is your definition of tensor?

Comment: A multidimensional array.

Comment: So if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $f \in H$, how would you construct a multidimensional array out of $f$?

Comment: Although, H only has the ability to contain an inner product, where as f is actually the inner product.  Okay I understand now.  Thank you so much.